# Tabs and photo gallery issue with html site

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a photo gallery, and the issue is this:
I have 2 tabs (Cars and Romania) from the photo gallery on my "photo gallery" page. Basically when you click on a thumbnail it should open the picture and you can see it. But on the second tab, when you click on the first 10 thumbnails it opens the pictures from the first tab.

The photo gallery can be found [here](http://c.sitagabriel.com/gallery.html).

I tried to change the links to the photos in HTML, but it still shows the first tabs images (only for the first 10 images on the second tab).

The photo gallery is made with JS and I don't know JS at all.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In HTML everything looks okey. It has to be something with scripts so you have to provide code of them for us. Then we might be able to find a solution.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. The script can be found here [link](http://www88.zippyshare.com/v/8bKNglFJ/file.html) The script is called slippry. I think this is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide source code in your question, not let the users search for it.
By the way, your error comes from line 20 of `gallery/photo-gallery.js`:

```
$('a.controls').trigger('click');
```

Remove it and you will see the right image, until you'll click on `next` or `prev`.
This is because of a jQuery selector error on line 34:

```
var src = $('ul.row li:nth-child('+ index +') img').attr('src');
```

With this selector you are not looking in the right tab, but just for the first result, that obviuously comes from the first tab.

**EDIT (added solution)**

To solve you problem:

Replace

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.controls', function(){
```

with

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.controls', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
```

and

```
var src = $('ul.row li:nth-child('+ index +') img').attr('src');
```

with

```
var activeTabSelector = $('#myTab li.active a').attr('href');
var src = $(activeTabSelector).find('ul li:nth-child('+ index +') img').attr('src');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I uploaded the photo-gallery.js here[link](http://www65.zippyshare.com/v/re1vcZ94/file.html) I added that line of code, and the first image is working. But if I click on "next" it gives me the 4th image. Same if I click on 10th image and click "nect" it gives me 4th iamge.

Comment: I used `4` as test variable and forgot to replace it with `index`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I replaced `4` with `index` and the site goes to [link](http://c.sitagabriel.com/4) with an `Internal Server Error` - why it gives this error?

Comment: This is because you are not preventing the default behavior of the click event. Check the last edit to know how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much mrnfrancesco, really appreciate it!